# Error while Indtalling EFCodeFirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I am developing ASP.NET MVC 3 music store site from the tutorial, Page 45.

When I am trying to install the EFCodeFirst I am getting the below error
Please help
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install EFCodeFirst when you have installed EntityFramework. Entity Framework is the latest version, EFCodeFirst was used during the beta.

Answer (score 0):

Update NuGet

from menu: Tools > Extension Manager

select update section from left menu